# Mongoose :Find and filter nested array

Tags: node.js, filter, mongoose, nested, find

I'm trying to find a whole document with `Find()` command and filter a nested array with a condition.

Here a piece of the used Schema :

```
var ListSH = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true},
  subject : String,
  recipients : [
    Schema({
     uid : { type : ObjectId, required : true, ref:'User', unique: true},
     status : { type : Number, default : 1 }
     },{_id: false})
  ]
};
```

Currently I do `ListModel.findOne({ _id : req.params.id_list, function(err,list){...};`

And Postman give me that:

```
{
  "_id": "57e6bcab6b383120f0395aed",
  "name": "Emailing listname",
  "subject": "List subject",
  "recipients": [
    {
      "uid": "57e932bcbbf0e9e543def600",
      "status": 0
    },
    {
      "uid": "57e93266c3c0b1dc1625986f",
      "status": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like Postman to return me something like that by adding a `recipients.status : 1` condition

```
  {
      "_id": "57e6bcab6b383120f0395aed",
      "name": "Emailing listname",
      "subject": "List subject",
      "recipients": [
        {
          "uid": "57e93266c3c0b1dc1625986f",
          "status": 1
        }
      ]
    }
```

I've already tried `ListModel.findOne({ _id : req.params.id_list, 'recipients.status' : 1}, function(err,list){...};`

and something weird like `populate([$match('recipients.status : 1)]);`
but with no success..

Anyone knows ?
Thanks ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` to get it in an easy way like this

```
ListModel.aggregate(
    { $match: {_id: ObjectId("57e6bcab6b383120f0395aed")}},
    { $unwind: '$recipients'},
    { $match: {'recipients.status':1}})
```

**Output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57e6bcab6b383120f0395aed"),
    "name" : "Emailing listname",
    "subject" : "List subject",
    "recipients" : {
        "uid" : "57e93266c3c0b1dc1625986f",
        "status" : 1
    }
}
```

To understand aggregation in details see the docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Comment: This only returns a single $recipient, no matter how many answer the criteria.

Comment: I am getting error: `Expected 0-2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)
(property) 'recipients.status': number`

Answer (score 15):

Try below query:

```
ListModel.findOne({"_id" : "57e6bcab6b383120f0395aed", 'recipients.status' : 1},{_id:1, name: 1, subject:1,'recipients.$': 1}, function(err,list){...});
```

Comment: Both solutions worked for me !
Thanks sooo much for your help

Comment: @nicolas.grd Glad It helped!!

Comment: I like the clarity of this answer more than the accepted answer, both work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I proceed to delete this found object?

Comment: Thank you! I like your answer better, though all you needed was {'recipients.$': 1} for the second parameter. I get that this is a filter to limit the number of items to return.

Comment: great answer, thanks!