# How to update objects in list in mongoose (in NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an object with the following model:

```
export const Address = mongoose.model('Address',
    {   
        id: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
        customer_id: String,
        addresses: [{
            address_type: String,
            address_info: String,
        }]
    });
```

An example dataset is like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "address": [
      {
        "customer_id": "12345123",
        "addresses": [
        {
            "address_type": ANDROID,
            "address_info": "dfjghjsdgf"
        },
        {
            "address_type": IOS,
            "address_info": "dwrw45345f"
        }
        ]
      },
      {
        "customer_id": "12345124",
        "addresses": [
        {
            "address_type": SMS,
            "address_info": "dfjghj231dgf"
        },
        {
            "address_type": IOS,
            "address_info": "ww242344234"
        }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It's clear that the `addresses` field of the `Address` model is a list, within which each object has two fields : `address_type`, and `address_info`.

**I wonder how to update an `address_info` with filters in `customer_id` and `address_type`?** For example, if I would like to update **the `ANDROID` address of `customer_id = 12345123` to `abcdefg`**, it's expected to see the database being updated into :

```
{
  "data": {
    "address": [
      {
        "customer_id": "12345123",
        "addresses": [
        {
            "address_type": ANDROID,
            "address_info": "abcdefg"
        },
        {
            "address_type": IOS,
            "address_info": "dwrw45345f"
        }
        ]
      },
      {
        "customer_id": "12345124",
        "addresses": [
        {
            "address_type": SMS,
            "address_info": "dfjghj231dgf"
        },
        {
            "address_type": IOS,
            "address_info": "ww242344234"
        }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Reference: [Mongoose :Find and filter nested array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707813/mongoose-find-and-filter-nested-array/39707985#39707985)
This problem talked about **`findOne`**, but I'm more interested in **update**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this

```
await Address.update(
   { customer_id: "12345123", "addresses.address_type": "ANDROID" },
   {$set : { "addresses.$.address_info" : "abcdefg" }} 
)
```

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cG9TcEV7ELb)